# Deny direct access to a folder or file, but allow index.php to access it

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to block direct access to the music folder on my website which contains my music.(I want the music to be played, but not downloaded)

But I also want to be able to play the music on the browser, I blocked access using the .htaccess file, but because of this, I cannot play the songs on the browser.

My .htacces file looks like this. and it is inside the music folder.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
<FilesMatch "^$|(index)\.php$">
Allow from All
</FilesMatch>
```

Is there a way to do this, to play the song while direct access to the folder is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser can access the data, by definition, it is downloadable. However I've had some success in situations like yours with the following approach:

Create a `music.php` file that does two things:
1) Checks the request for 'timeliness', and
2) Uses `file_get_contents()` to serve the content (using the correct Content-Type) without revealing the path to your music directory.

The request could look like `http://blah.com/music/50/1521342509/j25ia920oj12501`.

- `/music/` is not a directory, but a `mod_rewrite` condition/rule (in your `.htaccess` file), sending the request to `music.php`
- `/50/` is the actual song name
- `1521342509` is the unix timestamp of the music request ... any requests more than a few seconds after this timestamp is likely a user attempt.
- `j25ia920oj12501` is a hash of that same time timestamp (sha256, truncated after 16 characters is plenty), to ensure the timestamp is authentic.

This is far from foolproof, but is entirely effective at preventing all but the most dedicated/clever from downloading your stuff.

Comment: Could you please explain with a sample code on how to do this??